# A bash script sometimes "skips" the first two characters of a statement. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: bash

I wrote a bash script that runs a partial sync from a remote staging database to a development database on the local machine (my Macbook). The script first dumps certain tables from the staging db (usually over SSH tunnel) to local .sql files, then executes those .sql files against the local db. Here's the script (some tables renamed to protect the guilty):

```
rm -rf export/
mkdir export

set -e # abort if any command in the script fails

abort() {
  echo $1
  exit 1
}

dump_table() {
  echo "Dumping to $1.sql..."
  pg_dump $DATABASE_URL -t $1 --data-only > export/$1.sql
}

[ -z "$DATABASE_URL" ] && abort "usage: DATABASE_URL=postgres://un:pw@localhost:55555/dbname sh bin/importdb.sh"

echo "_structure.sql..."
pg_dump $DATABASE_URL -s > export/_structure.sql

dump_table events
dump_table users
dump_table attendees
dump_table orders
dump_table admissions
dump_table teams
# etc...

echo ""
echo "Done with dump from staging!"
echo "Starting local import..."

# Prepend all dumpfiles with the ON_ERROR_STOP flag so the script will abort on error
for f in export/*.sql; do ex -sc '1i|\set ON_ERROR_STOP on' -cx $f; done

dropdb cello_development
createdb cello_development
psql -d cello_development -f export/_structure.sql

# Because we're only importing certain tables, we first need to remove
# a bunch of FKs so that references to un-imported tables are ignored.
psql -d cello_development -c "ALTER TABLE users DROP CONSTRAINT fk_rails_047fa7c340"
psql -d cello_development -c "ALTER TABLE users DROP CONSTRAINT fk_rails_752aed9fe5"
psql -d cello_development -c "ALTER TABLE events DROP CONSTRAINT fk_rails_e1c8c23245"
psql -d cello_development -c "ALTER TABLE events DROP CONSTRAINT fk_rails_1a56b1500c"
psql -d cello_development -c "ALTER TABLE events DROP CONSTRAINT fk_rails_ae012fe18a"
psql -d cello_development -c "ALTER TABLE events DROP CONSTRAINT fk_rails_95c0269b21"
# etc...

echo "events..."
psql -d cello_development -f export/events.sql
echo "users..."
psql -d cello_development -f export/users.sql
echo "attendees..."
psql -d cello_development -f export/attendees.sql
echo "orders..."
psql -d cello_development -f export/orders.sql
echo "admissions..."
psql -d cello_development -f export/admissions.sql
echo "teams..."
psql -d cello_development -f export/teams.sql
# etc...

echo ""
echo "Done with local db import!"
```

I run this script by first opening an ssh tunnel to allow me to access the remote (source) db, then running the script with the `DATABASE_URL` env var set. As you can see there's nothing fancy about the way I invoke the script:

```
# In one window, open an SSH tunnel so I can access the source db
ssh -NTL 55555:cello-staging.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 ubuntu@staging.cello.com

# In second window, run the script with DATABASE_URL set
DATABASE_URL=postgres://un:pw@localhost:55555/cello_staging sh bin/importdb.sh
```

Some of these tables are large (4m+ rows) so the script as a whole can take a couple hours to complete. (Yes I'm sure there's better ways to seed the dev database.)

**My problem is this**: frequently (~ 60% of the time) the script fails with errors that suggest that part of a statement got "skipped". One example:

```
# The failure message:
-bash: mp_table: command not found

# The statement at that line in the script:
dump_table admissions
```

Another example:

```
# The failure message:
bin/importdb.sh: line 65: port/admissions.sql: No such file or directory

# The statement at that line in the script:
psql -d cello_development -f export/admissions.sql
```

The failures are consistent with what I'd see if I ran the statement at that line, *without* the first two characters (always exactly two leading characters). For example, if I independently run the statement `dump_table admissions` (assuming the `dump_table` function is defined), I expect it to succeed; but if I independently run the statement `mp_table admissions`, I see the same failure message as above.

The failures tend to happen right after a couple particularly large table operations. But not all comparably-large tables are comparably affected.

My best guess is that somehow the expensive postgres DB operations being run, are causing the bash script to get confused and sometimes "skip" characters on the subsequent statement.

**My questions:**

- How would you go about troubleshooting this? when a statement in your bash script appears to be (sometimes) altered / shortened before execution?
- When executing a bash script, is it possible for side effects of earlier statements to somehow affect the wording of subsequent statements in the script?
- Is it possible that the `psql` & `pg_dump` commands I'm running are interacting with the contents of the script that's invoking them?

Context: I'm on MacOS 10.14, using iTerm2. The local db server is Postgres v9.6.

**Edit 1:** At no point is the script itself being modified. It's checked into Git, no changes show up, it's on my local machine, no user should have access to make changes to the file except for me.

**Edit 2:** Rewrote to include the full script being run as well as the full command I'm using to invoke it.

Comment: Does anything change between a working run and a failing run?  Is anybody modifying the script while it is running?

Comment: Any chance that the script files are being modified while running - either by the script itself, or maybe someone else is modifying them?  Have you checked the modification time on the script file(s) before and after the problem?

Comment: How are you actually running the script? It looks like something else is reading your script at the same time the shell executing it reads it.

Comment: @chepner ITYM "something else is *writing* your script at the same time".

Comment: @Jens Nope, reading. I'm picturing both the shell and another process reading from the same open file handle (say, both inheriting standard input from a process that actually opened the file for reading); the shell reads one line, but then the other process reads two characters before the shell has a chance to read the next line, so that it sees `mp_table ...` instead of `dump_table ...`: the other process read the `du`.

Comment: Consider using 'strace' on the bash command line. The script is usually placed on  255. Assuming the script is not modified (check ctime with ls -lc), it is possible that the script (or a children of it) is reading from fd255. Hopefully, strace will show some hints about the source of the problem

Comment: @chepner But different processes have different copies of the stdio buffers, including file offset. I fail to see how two different outcomes can result from reading an unchanging file. I've seen however many running scripts fail the moment they get written.

Comment: @Jens Not if they inherit the same file handle; consider `{ head; head; } < somefile.txt`. The shell opens `somefile.txt`, and both `head` processes inherit the same open file handle from the command group. The second `head` will start reading where the first one left off.

Comment: @chepner Hmm. I tried the head example on sh, bash and zsh, the second head seems to output nothing. I only ever see 10 lines. The input file has more than 10 lines. Is your shell different?

Comment: `head` might read more than 10 lines, even though it only outputs 10 lines, depending on buffering. Try `for ((i=0; i<10000; i++)); do echo $i; done | { head; head; }`.

Comment: @Jens I've seen the something-stealing-input effect when the script is passed via stdin, mostly when it's run over an ssh connection, like `ssh user@server <scriptfile`.

Comment: "Does anything change between a working run and a failing run? Is anybody modifying the script while it is running?" - @0x5453, emphatic no. The bash script is checked into git and does not change. It runs postgres commands such as `pg_dump`, `dropdb`, `createdb`, and `psql` to execute .sql files.

Comment: "Any chance that the script files are being modified while running" - @ewindes good thought; as far as I can tell, no. This is running on my local machine and is checked into git. No changes show up for the script files. No one should have access to the file (except me of course). This is a plain ol' locally-run bash script like any other. The only possible differentiating factors I can think of are: 1) the script takes a long time to run (90+ mins) due to the large db operations, and 2) it's running some `pg_dump` commands against a remote staging db.

Comment: "How are you actually running the script?" - @chepner the command I run is: `DATABASE_URL=postgres://un:pw@host:port/dbname sh bin/importdb.sh`.  I can't think of any way that some other rogue process might be reading the script at the same moment.

Comment: "I've seen the something-stealing-input effect when the script is passed via stdin, mostly when it's run over an ssh connection" - @GordonDavisson note that the `pg_dump` commands are executed against a **remote staging db** over ssh tunnel, I wonder if that's relevant somehow. The `psql` commands are executed against a local db. The error occurs both in the remote-dump step and the local-import step with similar frequency.

Comment: **Edited** to include the full script as well as the full command I'm running to invoke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what would make this happen, but have a couple of suggestions for troubleshooting/avoiding it.

- It really looks to me like something's stealing input from the shell. Try redirecting input for the commands before the problem occurs:

  ```
  pg_dump $DATABASE_URL -s > export/_structure.sql </dev/null

  dump_table events </dev/null
  dump_table users </dev/null
  ...etc
  ```

  If that keeps it from happening, you can try removing some of the redirects, until you've narrowed down which command(s) are causing the problem. Or you could just leave them all there...

  If that *doesn't* stop it happening, then I'm even more mystified than I am now.
- You could also try wrapping the entire script (except the shebang line) in a shell block of some sort, with an explicit exit at the end - something like `if true; then ... exit; fi` or even just `{ ... exit; }`. This will force the shell to read and parse the entire block before executing any of it (and exit before trying to execute anything after it), so if anything messes with the file or file descriptor or whatever won't matter:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  if true; then    # Workaround to avoid script reading weirdness
      rm -rf export/
      mkdir export

      ...

      exit
  fi
  ```

BTW, I do recommend using a proper shebang line at the beginning of the script, making it executable (`chmod +x bin/importdb.sh`), and then running directly without the `sh` command. Essentially, the script's author (via the script itself) should define what language/dialect/etc the script it written in, not the person (/outer script/cron entry/whatever) running it.

Comment: YES. Thank you. The `</dev/null` tip didn't prevent the errors but wrapping the entire script in an `if` statement did make them go away.